# Policy for a Private Staging S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I'd like my staging website at `staging.example.org` to be accessed in a private manner only. For example, as a user logged onto the AWS console, can I give private access to myself only?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "logged into AWS."  If you are talking about accessing it from the S3 section of the AWS console, that's one thing... but I'm inclined to suspect that you mean something different.  Please advise.

Comment: I'm not sure you are conveying your intention, or I may still be reading between the lines of what you are hoping for.  It isn't possible to access a bucket *because* you are logged into the console.  You can only access the contents of the bucket *using* the console -- not in another browser window.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all access to Amazon S3 is private.

You can then grant access to S3 buckets in two ways:

- **Add a policy to an IAM User or Group** that allows them to access a specific bucket, or
- **Add a bucket policy** that grants access to specific users/groups

The first method is slightly better because you can add permissions for multiple buckets, whereas the second method would need to be done on each bucket for which you wish to grant access.

See documentation and articles like: [Writing IAM Policies: How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

Comment: Thank you, I’m aware of this. I must really be failing to ask the question correctly. The access I’m trying to provide is simply access to the static website hosted on that bucket.

Comment: If you are talking about accessing a static website via a web browser, there is no method to identify the users. You could limit access by IP address, but you cannot really lock it down to particular "users" since there are no "users" on static websites (unless you do fancy stuff with pre-signed URLs).

Comment: There you go, that’s what I thought, hence my question to make sure there was no actual way of doing this hidden within the AWS docs. I’m sorry the question was so vague.